# How can I use sparse grid techniques for a hyperboloid

Tags: python, sparse-matrix

Is there a class in Python that produces a sparse grid for a hyperboloid? I am trying to integrate across an n-dimensional hyperboloid, and a sparse grid would help me to save a lot of memory.